# Matlab ransac parameters meaning. I got "Could not find enough inliers. Try increasing MaxDistance"? Is there a minimum number of inliers required?

Tags: matlab, ransac

I got an error message "Could not find enough inliers. Try increasing MaxDistance". The error message "Could not find enough inliers. Try increasing MaxDistance" indicate there is a threshold of the number of inliers, but I can not find any parameter related to this in the [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html).

Comment: Look at the documentation more closely. maxDistance isn’t one of the optional Name-Value parameters. It’s the last required input.

Comment: @FragileX I think neither of `ValidateModelFcn`, `MaxSamplingAttempts`, `MaxNumTrials` and `Confidence` represent "least number of inliers required".

Comment: You’re still looking in the “Name-Value Arguments” section. Scroll up to the “Input Arguments” section. Don’t look for a “number of inliers required” input, look for the “maxDistance” input.

Comment: @FragileX I do know this error message indicates increasing the value of `MaxDistance`. However, I can't find any description of `enough inliers` in the ransac algorithm. This message indicates  “number of inliers required” , but I can not find corresponding desricption in ransac algorithm[(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus)

Comment: True, there’s no way to decrease the required number of max inliers. The way to accommodate the spread in your data is to increase the maxDistance until enough of your points fall within this distance to qualify as inliers.

Comment: @FragileX After some debugging, I think the “least number of inliers required” is just `1`. It seems this error message is misleading, it seems to be caused by "no inlier is found", am I correct?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. You didn’t provide any code, so I can’t do any research. Are you not able to just increase the maxDistance until `ransac` to gives you a usable output?